# Freeing pointer arrays

Tags: c

Suppose I have the following `main` function:

```
int main(void) {
    char * strings[] = { "a", "b", "c", NULL};
    char **xstrings = malloc (4 * sizeof *xstrings);
}
```

What would be the proper way to `free` the xstrings? Examples are:

```
free(xstrings)
```

Or:

```
    while (*xstrings) {  
        free (*xstrings);    
        *xstrings++ = NULL;  
    }
}
```

What would be the difference between the two ways, and is one right and the other wrong, or how are they different?

Comment: Just use `free(xstrings)`. I don't see that there's any reason for the second version because no memory was allocated for the inner pointer, and even if it had been, seems like UB because you're incrementing a pointer that was just freed. Is this the complete example?

Comment: Where did you see this code?

Comment: @ggorlen got it -- if the `**xstrings` had any values set, would I need to free both? Or does doing `free (xstrings)` automatically free everything inside it?

Comment: The first option. The rule is: for every `malloc` you need a `free`. So if you'd allocated memory for `xstrings[i]`, you'd need to loop over each one and free it, then free the memory allocated for `xstrings`. If you do `free(xstrings)` without freeing everything it's pointing to, that's a memory leak.

Comment: @ggorlen ah, ok, so memory needs to be freed from the inner-most place (if it exists) to the outer?

Comment: @ggorlen want to add in an answer and I'll go ahead and accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is correct, although the

```
char * strings[] = { "a", "b", "c", NULL};
```

line is unused.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char **xstrings = malloc(4 * sizeof *xstrings);
    free(xstrings);
    return 0;
}
```

Above, we allocate space for 4 `char *` pointers and correctly free the memory.

Typically, though, we'd want to allocate memory for each of the `char *` pointers (we can't achieve anything meaningful unless the `xstrings` variable eventually points to some data):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int len = 4;
    char **xstrings = malloc(len * sizeof *xstrings);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        xstrings[i] = malloc(sizeof(*xstrings[i]) * some_length);
    }

    /* ... do something with the memory ... */

    /* free each xstring element */

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        free(xstrings[i]);
    }

    free(xstrings);
    return 0;
}
```

The lines

```
while (*xstrings) {  
    free (*xstrings);    
    *xstrings++ = NULL;  
}
```

don't make much sense. Once memory is `free`d, it cannot be used. You can use temporary variables to achieve this, but it'd be a bit of a pain compared to simply using a `for` loop (we don't want to abandon the original `xstrings` pointer so we can free it later and we'd need a temporary variable in the loop to call `free` on after moving the pointer forward).